# ServiceHost.BeginOpen blocks the caller thread

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I use the ServiceHost in a WPF application. When I call the ServiceHost.Open method it takes about 30 seconds to complete (I connect to a Azure ServiceBus. The long wait time seems to come from our company internet proxy).

Because it takes that long I would like that this call does not block the Dispatcher thread and it should support Cancellation. Unfortunately, the ServiceHost does not support the Task API but it is easy to create one:

```
public static class CommunicationObjectExtensions
{
    public static Task OpenAsync(this CommunicationObject co, CancellationToken token)
    {
        token.Register(() => co.Abort());

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(co.BeginOpen(null, null), co.EndOpen);
    }
}
```

Why does the ServiceHost.BeginOpen call block the Dispatcher thread? The MSDN documentation says the BeginOpen will be done asynchronously. This way the Dispatcher thread should not be blocked.

Comment: i encountered this issue also in my development, what usually happens is one of the call, during the async drill, is not using async-await properly. how about makin public static async Task OpenAsync(...) await Task.Run(your task) ?

Comment: Yes, I can call this in an own task. But (1) I'm not sure if the ServiceHost is thread safe; (2) calling Abort does not work. Any ideas?